# @min and @NotNull annotations not working I have imported the required library but still not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

```
Last name(*):  <form:input path="lastName"/>
<form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>
<br><br>
Free passes: <form:input path="freePasses" />
<form:errors path="freePasses" cssClass="error" />
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

```
@NotNull(message="is required")
@Size(min=1, message="is required")
private String lastName;
    
@Min(value=0,message="must be greater than or equal to zero")
@Max(value=10,message="must be less than or equal to ten")
private int freePasses;
```

```
public String processForm(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer,BindingResult theBindingResult)
```

I have called the bean validation annotations but it is not working when I write in the form it goes to the output and not showing any errors.I have the valid annotations also and also used getters and setters, imported the necessary libraries but still not working.

Comment: Make sure the @valid annotation is present in your controller.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, post the code as code-formatted text. Also make sure you post it as a [mre].